# Programmatically populate an ASP.net data table

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, gridview

I'm trying to show a Sharepoint list on an ASP page that's running on a different server to the Sharepoint site. I originally tried using the Server Object Model, but with no success (see: [Using Sharepoint GridViews on server without SharePoint installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747907/using-sharepoint-gridviews-on-server-without-sharepoint-installed))

So I have settled for using the Client Object Model instead. Now this allows me to pull data from Sharepoint, however, and please correct me if I'm wrong, there is no built in functionality that allows you to bind ASP.net data tables/grid views to Sharepoint objects. The ASP.net page runs on a server that does not have Sharepoint installed.

I would very much like to use ASP.net grid view objects, as they're very design friendly (visible in the GUI) and provide a whole host of functionality - sorting, paging, and so on. These objects need to consume ASP data sets afaik (I'm new to ASP.net development), so I've created a data set object, and a data table to source the data from.

These data tables are clearly designed to retreive data from SQL based sources, as the only options Visual Studio provides for populating them is from the various SQL platforms. However I was able to use the GUI to add the columns I wanted to the data table. These column names correspond to columns of metadata in the Sharepoint list I want to retreive from.

Now can anyone provide me with the steps - preferably with regard to best practice, that I need to go through in order to ensure that the grid view is populated with values when the user loads the page. I already know how to access the values via the Sharepoint web service, but I'm just not sure how to get them into the ASP data set.

Answer (score 0):

By making use of the [GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29) method, I can have all the items of a particular list in the form of XML node. All I need is to convert this XML into data set. Here is how you can convert the XML node to DataSet. You can iterate through the xml nodes and create rows to your dataset as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894451/import-xml-into-dataset-c-sharp).